# Вылетает приложение с определением местоположения

Tags: android, gps

Здравствуйте!
Есть простенькое приложение для определения местоположения. При запуске оно выдает ошибку. Не могу понять в чем дело. Кто может помочь? (Тестирую на Android 4.4.2)

Вот код активности:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private LocationListener mLocationListener;
    private Location mLocation;
    private TextView mLatitudeTextView, mLongitudeTextView;

    private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // в метрах
    private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 2000; // в мс

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mLatitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLatitude);
        mLongitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLongitude);

        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        String provider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        mLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        mLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();

        showCurrentLocation(mLocation);

        // Регистрируемся для обновлений
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,
                MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, MINIMUM_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATES,
                mLocationListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        showCurrentLocation(mLocation);
    }

    protected void showCurrentLocation(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            mLatitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
        }
    }

    // Прослушиваем изменения
    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            String message = "Новое местоположение Долгота: " +
            location.getLongitude() + "Широта: " + location.getLatitude();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            showCurrentLocation(mLocation);
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Статус провайдера изменился",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Провайдер заблокирован пользователем. GPS выключен",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Провайдер включен пользователем. GPS включён",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

В манифесте прописал

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

На всякий случай код разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonUpdate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Обновить данные" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Широта (Latitude): " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLatitude"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Долгота (Longitude): " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLongitude"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**UPD1**

А вот это в логе выделено красным:

```
04-21 11:46:11.443  11495-11495/com.example.irina.location E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.irina.location, PID: 11495

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.irina.location/com.example.irina.location.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null

 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)

 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)

            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)

            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)

            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)

            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)

            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)

            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)

            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)

            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null

            at android.location.LocationManager.checkProvider(LocationManager.java:1646)

            at android.location.LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.java:1167)

            at com.example.irina.location.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)

            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)

            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)

            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)

            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)

            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)

            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)

            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)

            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)

            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)

            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)

            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**UPD2**

В манифесте переместил разрешения и приложение запустилось :)  Но координаты не хочет показывать.

Добавил в код следующее

```
if (location == null) {
    mLatitudeTextView.setText("Не работает");
    mLongitudeTextView.setText("Не работает");
}
```

И приложение мне именно эти 2 текста и выдало.

Почему же `location` передается `null` ?

Comment: Какую ошибку пишет в лог?

Comment: На какой строке падает? Лог в студию

Comment: вот просто Caused by:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null

Comment: Перезагрузил планшет, и заработало ...

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> String provider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
> ```

В данной строке запрашиваются только включенные источники местоположения, т.к. у вас выключены все, то возвращается null

Comment: Дак все включено вроде как. И, например, приложения GoogleMap, 2ГИС и другие сразу определяют мое местоположение

Comment: GoogleMap использует fused location provider

Comment: В манифесте переместил разрешения и приложение запустилось :) Но координаты не хочет показывать.

Добавил в код следующее if (location == null) { mLatitudeTextView.setText("Не работает"); mLongitudeTextView.setText("Не работает"); }

И приложение мне именно эти 2 текста и выдало.

Почему же location передается null ?

Answer (score 0):

Падает на `MainActivity` в 41 строке, при вызове метода `getLastKnownLocation()`. Вероятно в настройках телефона отключено определение местоположения по Gps и Network, попробуйте включить.

Comment: Дак все включено вроде как. И, например, приложения GoogleMap, 2ГИС и другие сразу определяют мое местоположение